# Hostapd hotspot not running

Tags: debian, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I installed and set-up hotspot using hostapd.

```
# /etc/init.d/hostapd start
[ ok ] Starting hostapd (via systemctl): hostapd.service.
```

But when I try to connect my phone to the hotspot, it does not show up on the list.
Why is it so?
I use Debian on Gnome environment.

This is what my hostapd.conf file looks like:

```
interface=wlp3s0
ieee80211n=1
channel=6
bridge=br0
ssid=Pauling
wpa=2
country code=IN
wpa_passphrase=password
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIM
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
autht_algs=1
macaddr acl=0
# Change the broadcasted/multicasted keys after this many seconds.
wpa_group_rekey=600
# Change the master key after this many seconds. Master key is used as a     basis
wpa_gmk_rekey=86400
```

Edit: The error in journalctl -b -u hostapd is:

```
Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd failed!
```

That's all.

Comment: I don't see a `hw_mode`; this defaults to 802.11b.  Are you sure your phone can see "b" networks?  What happens if you add `hw_mode=g` ?  That other thing to verify is that your `wl` interface name is correct.  Does this match what `iwconfig` says?

Comment: @StephenHarris I tried changing it to both b and g. None of them worked. The interface name is correct. The wlan0 has been changed to wlp3s0 in new kernel or something.

Comment: Does your hardware / driver [support hotspot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405282/finding-capabilities-of-wifi-driver-device)?

Comment: @Fabby Yes, it supports hotspot. I used to do it all the time when I had Ubuntu.

Comment: @sourcejedi I have edited in the journalctl log.

Comment: OK.  It looks like the way to see specific hostapd logs is to stop hostapd and manually run `sudo hostapd -d` .  I don't know hostapd and I don't know whether that's likely to help, but it is what I would try.  There is also a suggestion that NetworkManager can get in the way when you try to setup hostapd yourself.  https://gist.github.com/Semant1ka/ee087c2bd1fbf6b0287c3307b8d4f291

Comment: BTW, this does not help with your problem, but if you are curious why hostapd reported OK when actually it had failed, I found out why and [reported it as a bug in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=928888) . It already shouldn't happen in the next version of Debian.